# Add function not working - what I want is to be able to sum two matrices

Tags: python

I want to sum two matrices, so I'm doing the `__add__` method, but it doesn’t seem to work. Can somebody help me please? I don’t know what I'm doing wrong. This is my code:

```
class Matrix():

    def __init__(self, width = int, height = int, fill_value=0):
        self.height = height #columna
        self. width = width #fila
        self.rows = [[fill_value] * width for _ in range (height)] #A for matrix A

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n" .join(" ".join(map(str, self.rows))for self.rows in self.rows)

    def set(self, row_index = int, column_index = int, value = int):
        self.rows[row_index][column_index] = value

    def get(self, row_index, column_index):
        return self.rows[row_index][column_index]

    def __add__(self, other):
        matrix_addition = []
        for i in range(self.height):
            new_row = []
            for j in range(self.width):
                addition = self.rows[i][j] + other.rows[i][j]
                new_row.append(addition)
            matrix_addition.append(new_row)

        return Matrix(matrix_addition)
```

I'm having an error that says:

```
  addition = self.rows[i][j] + other.rows[i][j],
    TypeError : ‘int’ object has no attribute ‘__getitem__’
```

Comment: What code doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Where is the sum function? Do you mean add?

Comment: You don't seem to be passing the correct arguments to initialise your Matrix instance in `__add__`

Comment: Yeah sorry i meant add function, and the problem is i can’t add my two diferrent matrixes, i got an error that says “ addition = self.rows[i][j] + other.rows[i][j], TypeError : ‘int’ object has no attribute ‘__getitem__’

Comment: What are the shapes of your matrices. It seems as though either `self.rows[i]` or `other.rows[i]` are returning integer values rather than a sub-array. You could check by inserting a `breakpoint` before the `addition = ...` and printing those values. You could also create some unit tests to confirm the proper shape of your matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty good, you almost got it.

The first issue is your constructor and the `set()` method: by using
the default `value=int` in the parameters, you're essentially assigning `type(int)`, which is not what you want. You should either assign a default value, say `2` or use type hinting to specify data type, say `int`. Here's an example with both type hinting and defaults:

```py
   def __init__(self, width: int = 2, height: int = 2, fill_value=0):
      pass

   def set(self, row_index: int, column_index: int, value: int):
      pass
```

Here is the fatal error in your `__add__` method: `return Matrix(matrix_addition)`. This creates a new Matrix object and passes `matrix_addition` as an argument. However, the first argument in `Matrix.__init__` is `width`, which expects an `int`, not `List[List[int]]`. Instead, call `return matrix_addition` and it will work.

Comment: @Cam does this response answer your question? If so please click the green check mark on the left to indicate that it has been answered.